# Truffle error: Recipient address error

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

Whenever i run `truffle migrate` for any contract i get the following error:

```
Error: Attempting to run transaction which calls a contract function, but recipient address 0xc3041510ef6e2d9f4352c974093dd9f92108067a is not a contract address
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/home/vinayak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
    at /home/vinayak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
    at /home/vinayak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/vinayak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/vinayak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/vinayak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/vinayak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/vinayak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Contents of migration file:

1_inital_migration:

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

2_delpoy_contracts:

```
var DappToken = artifacts.require("./DappToken.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(DappToken,1000000); // passing an arg to constructor
};
```

I have tried changing ports and even making a contract form scrath.

Comment: what's your migration file?

Comment: 1_initial_migration.js and 2_deploy_contracts.js

Comment: please share the content of both

Comment: i have edited the question with the contents

Comment: try truffle migrate --reset

Comment: I've formulated an answer please accept to help other developers who re in the same situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error behind that might be a previous migration. 
in truffle, Changing the smart contract or deployment script after migration imply that we re-run `truffle migrat --reset` to commit changes.